# MySQL get top 10 items matching other table to group them

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

Maybe the title is not well explained.
I have this:

```
users (id, name)
-----------------------
|  1  |  User 1   | US |
|  2  |  User 2   | US |
|  3  |  User 3   | FR |
|  4  |  User 4   | IT |
|  5  |  User 5   | US |
| ... |  ......   | .. |
------------------------

games (game_id, user_id)
---------------
|  1 |   2    |
|  2 |   4    |
|  3 |   1    |
|  4 |   6    |
| ...|  ...   |
---------------
```

What I need is to get the top countries playing games, so an answer like:

```
1   US   145 games
2   FR    25 games
3   IT    12 games
...
up to 10 results
```

My solution is this, but it's too slow (have millions of records)

```
select 
  distinct(user.country), 
  count(*) as counter 
from games
  inner join user on games.user_id = user.id 
group by user.country 
order by counter DESC
limit 10
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a keyword, not a function. The parens around `user.country` are unnecessary; they do not influence on the statement. Actually, the `DISTINCT` keyword is unnecessary on this query, since there is a `GROUP BY user.country` clause.

Comment: I recommend you use `EXPLAIN` to verify that the query is using suitable indexes for the JOIN operation. And you could update your question with the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. The quick answer is provide suitable indexes for MySQL to use, but it doesn't make sense to give that answer without knowing what MySQL is doing.

Comment: About how many games per user?  What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: Also show the `explain plan` in the question next time, when you need help on performance.

Answer (score 0):

For optimum performance, MySQL needs to have suitable indexes available.

For this query, looks like you'd want these indexes:

```
... ON users (country, id)

... ON games (user_id)
```

**EXPLANATION**

You want an index with `country` as a leading column, so MySQL can use the index to perform the GROUP BY operation, rather than using an expensive "Using filesort" operation.

Having the user `id` column available as a secondary column in that index means it will be a covering index, and MySQL doesn't need to visit pages in the underlying table.

An index on the games table with a leading column of `user_id` means that MySQL can use the index to get the count.

We'd expect MySQL to show "Using index" in the Extra column from EXPLAIN.